# How to Reverse Sentence in Node Js environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

> ```
> I'm doing a practice coding problem and my code doesn't work in this particular environment, how do I get my code work and print multiple lines of sentences backwards. My code starts at "Line 15"
> ```

[These are the instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkicu.png)

[My code starts at Line 15 and I'm not sure what all the other code means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2Qaz.png)

[With the output i'm not sure why I'm not getting the right answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gZeh.png)

Comment: Don't post images of code. Paste (and format) the code in the question like all the other questions you see here.

Comment: [Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: Okay, thank you! @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `\b` which will split "w'w" into `w` `'` `w`.

A better way is to split using `space`.

```js
function reverse(input){
  return input.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');
}

console.log(reverse('Hello world'));
console.log(reverse('Hello world 123'));
```

Comment: I passed the initial input questions but it also says "You are given an integer N, followed by N lines of input (1 <= N <= 100). Each line of input contains one or several words separated with single spaces. Each word is a sequence of letters of English alphabet containing between 1 and 10 characters, inclusive. The total number of words in the input is between 1 and 100, inclusive.

Your task is to reverse the order of words in each line of input, while preserving the words themselves. The lines of your output should not have any trailing or leading spaces" How do I go abt doing more lines